# What are the way to clean flutter project, I have tried all the below ways but having same issue and unable to upload in Play console

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-layout, google-play

[image]I am uploading with correct signin key, few time I cleaned with

`flutter clean`

From android studio - clean project

Invalidate Caches

Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again. Your app bundle is expected to be signed with the certificate with fingerprint:[image]

[image]/MO2Pu.png

Answer (score 1):

You're signing a newer release with a different key as in regards to an older one. There are only two fixes.
Either find your old keystore and sign this release with it too.
Or contact Playconsole in regards to a forgotten key and the new key that you want to use, this way you'll be able to upload this new one with this new key.

Comment: I am using the same certificate, that's why I have added the picture from the play store console and my signing key. Check both is same.